# Semi continuous section in LP format file provided to cbc crashes

Tags: solver, continuous, coin-or-cbc

I am using version 2.9.9 of cbc in ubuntu 17.10 docker image. My test.lp file has following content:

```
Maximize
 obj: x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 + x4
Subject To
 c1: - x1 + x2 + x3 + 10 x4 <= 20
 c2: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
 c3: x2 - 3.5 x4 = 0
Bounds
 0 <= x1 <= 40
 2 <= x4 <= 3
General
 x4
Semis
 x1 x2 x3
```

When trying with semis section i get error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CoinError?' Aborted"

on mac i get: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CoinError? Abort trap: 6

However if I comment out Semis it works fine. I was hoping that Semis are supported. Am I doing something wrong?

My command is : `cbc -presolve on -import test.lp solve solu out.txt`

On further analysis i found out when in cbc prompt i type "import test.lp" it fails and shows same error is

Answer (score 0):

The CBC MPS file reader seems not to accept `SC` bounds either. I think CBC actually supports semi-continuous variables (I tested with a small GAMS model) but it seems difficult to pass it on in an LP or MPS file. As a work around, I would suggest to use binary variables to model semi-continuous behavior:

```
b * L ≤ x ≤ b * U
b in {0,1}
```